# WPF TextBox binding to decimal respecting culture

Tags: wpf, binding, localization

I've bound a TextBox to a Decimal. My problem ist, the Binding is using american numerical standards, using a dot for decimals separation ("1.5")

My system is german and configured to use a comma as decimals separation ("1,5").

I need the TextBox binding to show and use a comma instead of a dot to separate decimals.

How do I get the binding to respect the currently set localization/culture settings for numerical input?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read [this article](http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/04/wpf-tips-1-have-all-your-dates-times.html). You should set default language for all framework elements:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
    }
}
```

Comment: For Silverlight check [How to set Silverlight CurrentUICulture/CurrentCulture correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162050/how-to-set-silverlight-currentuiculture-currentculture-correctly/39387166#39387166)