# Any way to formatted value in specific language

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

while retrieve an entity 
the formatted values return dependent on systemuser language code

Is there any way to get formatted value (optionset) in language different than systemuser language

Comment: What kind of values do you mean? Doubles, ints, text?

Comment: option set text

Comment: Try changing your apps language like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723021/run-my-c-sharp-application-in-different-language

Answer (score 0):

You can either retrieve the metadata for the OptionSet, or impersonate a user with a different language code when retrieving the entity.

Comment: No impersonate a user with a different language code when retrieving the entity

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/impersonate-another-user