# How to change decimal operator according to the device culture in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I need to show the number keypad with the appropriate decimal separator for the culture. For example, Keypad should show the comma for de-DE (German).

Changing the language and region does not help. The keypad is still en-US.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming or C#? What OS even? It's either Phone or RT, there's no Phone RT. In Phone, there is no numeric keypad  it's a different on-screen keyboard. Which means, you'd need a different keyboard installed if you wanted different layouts. Changing the application's locale doesn't change the keyboard, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Are you looking for [this perhaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878877/wpf-textbox-binding-to-decimal-respecting-culture)? How to set the [Language property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc963438(v=vs.95).aspx) for all UIElements in your application?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Kindly read the title carefully :) there's no phone RT? There's WP8.1 Silverlight and WP8.1 RT. WP does not support installing external keyboards either.

Comment: As you yourself mentioned, and I also mentioned, there is WP, and there is Windows RT. There is no WP RT. As for no support for keyboards, just go to settings, Keyboard and select the keyboard from a list of dozens. Anyway, never mind me, I'm dumb and my phone is magic. You still need to fix the question so that others, smarter than me, can understand the question and answer it. What OS are you asking about and what is the exact question? Why is this *not* a duplicate question? Notice that your question hasn't attracted any other comments, much less answers